# 'gcloud app deploy' command not working

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a python version google app engine installed and I have created a new project in console. I followed the instruction in my terminal I use command `gcloud app deploy` in my working directory then I got this error:

```
ERROR: The [application] field is specified in file 
[/Users/fengxinlin/project/app.yaml]. This field is not used by 
gcloud and must be removed. Project name should instead be specified 
either by `gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT` or by setting the `-
-project` flag on individual command executions.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App 
Engine app configuration.
```

then I tried `gcloud config set project [one of my project]` after that I `gcloud app deploy` again, I got same error, is there any thing wrong with my command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now I solved this problem, The answer is just in the error message: in my `app.yaml` file, remove the `application` and `version` lines from the yaml file. then there will be no such errors.

Comment: Why does gcloud not allow/process "application" and "version" from inside app.yaml if not provided as an argument to it ?

Answer (score 5):

For me this was the command I needed:

```
gcloud app deploy --project project_name --version preprod --verbosity=info app.yaml index.yaml
```

My point of adding this answer is to note that using appcfg will work with the parameters : application and version, inside the app.yaml but appcfg won't work with the parameters to set other instance class and scaling (below). So **be careful if you return to appcfg just to have these parameters (version and application) working**

```
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

I had to update the ssl to :

```
- name: ssl
  version: "2.7.11"
```

Because clearly there is app engine bug and it doesn't work with

```
- name: ssl
      version: "latest"
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command before : **gcloud app deloy** : to get rid of the internal bug frustrating a lot of users like you and me.

```
gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True
```