# Ubuntu - Running gcloud app deploy command is throwing error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I was following along [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENrzD9HAZK4) tutorial on YouTube. I created an empty project on gcp, then ran `gcloud init` and switched to that project, then I ran `gcloud app deploy` and I ran into problems. In this tutorial video, it was not mentioned that I should enable Cloud Build API to deploy. So I don't know if only not enabling the Cloud Build API was the problem or something else was the problem.

Here's my app.yaml
`runtime: nodejs12`

I've tried many other stack overflow posts' answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512630/gcloud-app-deploy-command-not-working) one, but nothing worked for me. When I run `gcloud app deploy` when I am inside my new project, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Access Not Configured. Cloud Build has not been used in project XXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudbuild.googleapis.com/overview?project=[projectId] then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - x86-64.

Comment: Ok, but is not clear, did you try to enable the Cloud Build API? This is needed because Cloud Build will Build your code before deploying it to App Engine and I guess the tutorial did not mentioned it since it assumed you'd already have it enable. Also, keep in mind that you might have to wait for a few minutes to all be working properly after enabling the API.

Comment: @RafaelLemos I did try to enable the Cloud Build API, but asked for payment details. Is there a way to skip that step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must complete two steps:

1. Enable Google Cloud Billing.
2. Enable Cloud Build API.

You cannot skip enabling Cloud Billing. Once you set up the Billing Account, you might have to wait a few minutes before you can enable APIs.

The first 120 minutes of Cloud Build time is free. Then you will be charged $.003 per minute.

The page is a collection of documents on Google Cloud Billing.

[Google Cloud Billing Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs)

You can enable the Cloud Build API in the console or via the CLI.

[Enable Cloud Build API in the console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudbuild.googleapis.com)

```
gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com
```

[gcloud services enable](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable)